# Confused about the central and side pawns - which are which?

Tags: terminology, pawns, center

We all know that the "center" comprises of the four squares that are in the very middle of the board - d4, d5, e4, e5.

Keeping this in mind, which are the central pawns, exactly, apart from the ones on the d and e files? Do they include the c, d, e and f pawns? Also, if a pawn not on a central file captures a piece and comes one file closer to the center, is that pawn a central one now, too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The central pawns are strictly the pawns which are on the d and e files. You can think of them as pawns which have the ability to *occupy* the central squares at some point of the game.

The c and f pawns are called the “flank pawns”. The flank pawns can also be used to try and exert an early control of the center, for example in the English Opening (for White) or the Sicilian Defense (for Black).

Yes. The flank pawns may become central pawns by capturing.

You may see [this post](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/23262/what-types-of-pawns-are-there) for further reading.